# How to Delete/Ignore missing files from Version Control in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

I am trying to remove a lot of missing files from Version Control, Default folder/branch, but Delete/Ignore options are missing from the menu. Are there any other ways to do this? Thank's!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by missing files? According to the screenshots, files are already deleted, so are marked as deleted in the VCS. You now need to commit the deletion.

It is not possible to ignore files that are already tracked in the VCS, so to add them to ignored list you need, you need to stop tracking files in the VCS first.

Comment: When I tried to commit, I got this error: 

Commit failed with error
  0 files committed, 175 files failed to commit: ***
  svn: ***: Commit failed (details follow):
  svn: ***: 'D:\Home\***\***\***\***\***\***\***\***\dialog-background.png.bak' is scheduled for addition, but is missing